# Python, regex to exclude matches of numbers

Tags: python, regex

To use regex to extract any numbers of length greater than 2, in a string, but also exclude "2016", here is what I have:

```
import re

string = "Employee ID DF856, Year 2016, Department Finance, Team 2, Location 112 "

print re.findall(r'\d{3,}', string)
```

output:

```
['856', '2016', '112']
```

I tried to change it to below to exclude "2016" but all failed.

```
print re.findall(r'\d{3,}/^(!2016)/', string)
print re.findall(r"\d{3,}/?!2016/", string)
print re.findall(r"\d{3,}!'2016'", string)
```

What is the right way to do it? Thank you.

**the question was extended, please see the final comment made by Wiktor Stribiżew for the update.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "Employee ID DF856, Year 2016, Department Finance, Team 2, Location 112 20161 12016 120162"
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?!2016(?!\d))\d{3,}', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ALMm99) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGMCPq/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed iommediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!2016(?!\d))` - no `2016` not followed with another digit is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d{3,}` - 3 or more digits.

An alternative solution with some code:

```
import re
s = "Employee ID DF856, Year 2016, Department Finance, Team 2, Location 112 20161 12016 120162"
print([x for x in re.findall(r'\d{3,}', s) if x != "2016"])
```

Here, we extract any chunks of 3 or more digits (`re.findall(r'\d{3,}', s)`) and then filter out those equal to `2016`.

Comment: sir. thank you for the sharing and help again, the alternative solution, which is a baby way is brilliant!

Comment: @MarkK Well, I just wanted to show how it can be done with a single `re.findall` call, and someone disliked my idea. Anyway, I was going to add the second solution, just some people tend to complain about non-regex answers for regex questions. And vice versa :) We cannot please everyone on SO.

Comment: sir. is there a regex way to exclude "2017", "2016" and any "000" like numbers from the extraction? thank you.

Comment: @MarkK There are two ways. If you use the first solution, add these patterns to the negative lookahead: `r'(?<!\d)(?!(?:201[67]|000)(?!\d))\d{3,}'`. If you are using the second, `if x not in ['2016', '2017', '000']` or something (you may even use another simple regex there). I actually do not quite get what you mean by "000 like numbers". If you want to match numbers of 4 or more digits, use `\d{4,}` in the main pattern.

Comment: superb, sir! can't imagine how many years the human history will back-warded without encouraging and sharing spirits like yours!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a negative lookahead. The correct syntax is:

```
\D(?!2016)(\d{3,})\b
```

Results in:

```
In [24]: re.findall(r'\D(?!2016)(\d{3,})\b', string)
Out[24]: ['856', '112']
```

Or using a negative lookbehind:

```
In [26]: re.findall(r'\D(\d{3,})(?<!2016)\b', string)
Out[26]: ['856', '112']
```

Comment: thank you for the help and several edits. hope you don't mind I choose another one which provides more details for the solution. I upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: @MarkK Besides, this solution won't work for numbers at the start of the string.

Comment: But you can make it work for starting digits with a little change: [`(?:\D|^)(?!2016\b)(\d{3,})`](https://regex101.com/r/RtBjE4/2). Further regarding lookbehind version, be aware that it matches such as `102016`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this can be:

```
st="Employee ID DF856, Year 2016, Department Finance, Team 2, Location 112 "
re.findall(r"\d{3,}",re.sub("((2)?(016))","",st))
```

output will be:

```
['856', '112']
```

but accepted answer I see is a faster method than my suggestion.